# PySpark - Convert to JSON row by row

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very large pyspark data frame. I need to convert the dataframe into a JSON formatted string for each row then publish the string to a Kafka topic. I originally used the following code.

```
for message in df.toJSON().collect():
        kafkaClient.send(message)
```

However the dataframe is very large so it fails when trying to `collect()`.

I was thinking of using a `UDF` since it processes it row by row.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct

def get_row(row):
    json = row.toJSON()
    kafkaClient.send(message) 
    return "Sent"

send_row_udf = F.udf(get_row, StringType())
df_json = df.withColumn("Sent", get_row(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
df_json.select("Sent").show()
```

But I am getting an error because the column is inputed to the function and not the row.

For illustrative purposes, we can use the df below where we can assume Col1 and Col2 must be send over.

```
df= spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("D", 3)],["Col1", "Col2"])
```

The JSON string for each row:

```
'{"Col1":"A","Col2":1}'
'{"Col1":"B","Col2":2}'
'{"Col1":"D","Col2":3}'
```

Comment: Could  this work? `json = df.apply(lambda x: getattr(x, 'to_json')(), axis=1)`

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Comment: @JamesSchinner It is not Pandas

Comment: Oh, sorry, I stupidly thought it was a `pandas` df

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @pault `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `select` like this. Use `foreach` / `foreachPartition`:

```
import json

def send(part):
    kafkaClient = ...
    for r in part:
        kafkaClient.send(json.dumps(r.asDict()))
```

If you need diagnostic information just use `Accumulator`.

In current releases I would use Kafka source directly (2.0 and later):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct

(df.select(to_json(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])).alias("value"))
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers)
    .option("topic", topic)
    .save())
```

You'll need Kafka SQL package for example:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.1
```

Comment: I get this error `ImportError: cannot import name to_json`. I am using spark 1.6.3. Unfortunately I can't use the latest version.

Comment: In that case you're stuck with the first one. There is no Kafka SQL for such an outdated version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that should work for you.

Collect the column names (keys) and the column values into lists (values) for each row. Then rearrange these into a list of key-value-pair tuples to pass into the `dict` constructor. Finally, convert the `dict` to a string using `json.dumps()`.

**Collect Keys and Values into Lists**

Collect the column names and the values into a single list, but interleave the keys and values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def kvp(cols, *args):
    a = cols
    b = map(str, args)
    c = a + b
    c[::2] = a
    c[1::2] = b
    return c

kvp_udf = lambda cols: f.udf(lambda *args: kvp(cols, *args), ArrayType(StringType()))
df.withColumn('kvp', kvp_udf(df.columns)(*df.columns)).show()
#+----+----+------------------+
#|Col1|Col2|               kvp|
#+----+----+------------------+
#|   A|   1|[Col1, A, Col2, 1]|
#|   B|   2|[Col1, B, Col2, 2]|
#|   D|   3|[Col1, D, Col2, 3]|
#+----+----+------------------+
```

**Pass the Key-Value-Pair column into `dict` constructor**

Use `json.dumps()` to convert the `dict` into JSON string.

```
import json
df.withColumn('kvp', kvp_udf(df.columns)(*df.columns))\
    .select(
        f.udf(lambda x: json.dumps(dict(zip(x[::2],x[1::2]))), StringType())(f.col('kvp'))\
        .alias('json')
    )\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------------+
#|json                      |
#+--------------------------+
#|{"Col2": "1", "Col1": "A"}|
#|{"Col2": "2", "Col1": "B"}|
#|{"Col2": "3", "Col1": "D"}|
#+--------------------------+
```

**Note**: Unfortunately, this will convert all datatypes to strings.