# pyspark convert row to json with nulls

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Goal:**
For a dataframe with schema

```
id:string
Cold:string
Medium:string
Hot:string
IsNull:string
annual_sales_c:string
average_check_c:string
credit_rating_c:string
cuisine_c:string
dayparts_c:string
location_name_c:string
market_category_c:string
market_segment_list_c:string
menu_items_c:string
msa_name_c:string
name:string
number_of_employees_c:string
number_of_rooms_c:string
Months In Role:integer
Tenured Status:string
IsCustomer:integer
units_c:string
years_in_business_c:string
medium_interactions_c:string
hot_interactions_c:string
cold_interactions_c:string
is_null_interactions_c:string
```

I want to add a new column that is a JSON string of all keys and values for the columns. I have used the approach in this post [PySpark - Convert to JSON row by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542089/pyspark-convert-to-json-row-by-row) and related questions.
My code

```
df = df.withColumn("JSON",func.to_json(func.struct([df[x] for x in small_df.columns])))
```

I am having one issue:

**Issue:**
When any row has a null value for a column (and my data has many...) the Json string doesn't contain the key. I.e. if only 9 out of the 27 columns have values then the JSON string only has 9 keys... What I would like to do is maintain all keys but for the null values just pass an empty string ""

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to just modify the answer on the question you linked using [`pyspark.sql.functions.when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when).

Consider the following example DataFrame:

```python
data = [
    ('one', 1, 10),
    (None, 2, 20),
    ('three', None, 30),
    (None, None, 40)
]

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["A", "B", "C"])
sdf.printSchema()
#root
# |-- A: string (nullable = true)
# |-- B: long (nullable = true)
# |-- C: long (nullable = true)
```

Use `when` to implement [if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) logic. Use the column if it is not null. Otherwise return an empty string.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_json, struct, when, lit
sdf = sdf.withColumn(
    "JSON",
    to_json(
        struct(
           [
                when(
                    col(x).isNotNull(),
                    col(x)
                ).otherwise(lit("")).alias(x) 
                for x in sdf.columns
            ]
        )
    )
)
sdf.show()
#+-----+----+---+-----------------------------+
#|A    |B   |C  |JSON                         |
#+-----+----+---+-----------------------------+
#|one  |1   |10 |{"A":"one","B":"1","C":"10"} |
#|null |2   |20 |{"A":"","B":"2","C":"20"}    |
#|three|null|30 |{"A":"three","B":"","C":"30"}|
#|null |null|40 |{"A":"","B":"","C":"40"}     |
#+-----+----+---+-----------------------------+
```

---

Another option is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) instead of `when`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

sdf.withColumn(
    "JSON",
    to_json(
        struct(
           [coalesce(col(x), lit("")).alias(x) for x in sdf.columns]
        )
    )
).show(truncate=False)
## Same as above
```

Comment: Thanks! That gets me close. Only issue now is that the json string doesn't preserve the column names. I get {"col1": "val1", "col2": "", etc.} vs {"id": "val1", "IsCustomer": "", etc.}  This last point I'm 100% sure is a noob question... just can't figure it out

Comment: @mikeyoung I added an update- you just need to alias the column with the original name.

Comment: perfect, def a simple question ;)

Comment: This shouldn't be accepted answer because it works only for String DataType, if column is a different type the code throws an exception